# How to type inded signature in object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, styled-components

im new here. I am very sorry if I misnamed my problem.

I'd like to create a React component that will change the image source based on the prop given to it.

I'm stuck with a few bits of code.

`<CustomIcon type={'tooth'} />`

This is inside of a CustomIcon component

```
import React from 'react';
import { CustomIconProps } from './CustomIcon.types';
import { Img } from './CustomIcon.styles';

import iconPath from '../../assets/icons/iconPath';

export const CustomIcon: React.FC<CustomIconProps> = props => {
  return <Img src={iconPath[props.type]} />;
};
```

This is the inside of CustomIcon.types.ts

```
export type CustomIconProps = {
  type: string;
};
```

This is the inside of iconPath.ts

```
import tooth from './tooth.png';

const iconPath = {
  tooth: tooth,
};

export default iconPath;
```

And this is my bug:

```
TypeScript error in /home/buashei/work/reservation_module/src/components/CustomIcon/CustomIcon.tsx(15,20):
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Toot'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Toot'.  TS7053

    13 | 
    14 | export const CustomIcon: React.FC<CustomIconProps> = props => {
  > 15 |   return <Img src={iconPath[props.type]} />;
       |                    ^
    16 | };
    17 |
```

Please tell me where and how I should add types for "tooth".

Thanks in advance for your help with this problem, it fried my brain

Comment: Your error talks about `Toot` - is that another component or a typo?

Comment: @DeanJames `Toot` is an key and value in iconPath object. But i've found a solution of my problem. `export interface IconPathProps extends Record<string, string> {
  tooth: string;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Basically what it says is that you don't know that your `string` variable `props.type` represents a property of `iconPath`.  Instead of adding an index signature, I would restrict `props.type` such that it can only be a valid key and not just any `string`.

```
export type CustomIconProps = {
  type: keyof typeof iconPath;
};
```